# An isekai manga where the protagonist buys defective slaves (missing an arm or leg) heals them back to their best state and uses them to work for him

Tags: story-identification, manga, magic, isekai

The plot is that the main character he is in this other world with memories of life in japan so he was isekai. He the MC with the knowledge of his life in japan decides to make money by gathering defective slaves (missing an arm or leg, etc) and using healing magic he turns those slaves back to their best state and so he employs these slaves to raid dungeon , work at the post office, at the cafe he opens and etc.

after a while he gets engaged to a smoking blonde who can no longer do magic and eventually heals her magic core that she broke in the war, but he is the only one who can do this kind of heal the core. I think the manga had stopped here.... does anyone know the name of this manga?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: hello.
So if I'm not mistaken I read it at the beginning of the year maybe around March.... I read on mangakakalot.com that at the time it was the only manga website I accessed. I think at the time should have had around 20 chapters.

Comment: While you already have an answer, and the media is different, figured I'd mention that the *Super Sales on Super Heroes* book series starts with the same concept, with Felix, who can improve anything he owns, "accidentally" getting a shipment of horribly injured superheroines instead of the bismuth (he was planning to "improve" it to gold) he ordered. It gets a bit weirder and more corporate after that.

Comment: It's probably not important, but I wonder... Do you mean a [smoking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoking) blonde, or a [smoking hot](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/smoking_hot) blonde?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Living in another world by taking commissions](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/isekai-de-uwamae-hanete-ikiteiku-saisei-mahou-tsukai-no-yuru-fuwa-jinzai-haken-seikatsu).

You already summoned up the plot pretty well: the MC (who died of overworking in Japan) decides to enjoy an easy life in the new world by using his cheat restoration skill to heal "defective" slaves and make them work for him. He starts out with just an adventure group (in which he does not participate himself), but gradually increases the amount of slaves and businesses he owns.

The engagement and healing of his bride-to-be happens as well.

Comment: Thank you very much!
it was this manga.... i was looking in my manga list but i must have forgotten to save it, you helped me a lot